# unable to load Web browser from matlab

Tags: firefox, matlab

I am running Matlab under Ubuntu 18.04 on a shared machine. I am running Matlab as root from my account.
The reason I am running it as a root is that my Matlab code does many processes that require root privileges. When I run Matlab with non-root privileges it fails as permission is denied. Also, the menus in Simulink models are not displayed correctly.
So, I found that I am forced to run Matlab as root. As part of my workflow, I need to display the analysis results as html file. I tried using “web” command with Matlab browser and system browser.
With Matlab browser: I get this error
Warning - File or URL Not Found
MATLAB cannot link to this file or URL:

```
/home/myuser/Desktop/Matlab_2019b/xxx/xx/examples/demo/output/ABC_PP/ABC_PP_verificationResults_27-Jun-2020-13:22:38.html
```

I made sure that the path of the file location is added to Matlab path.
When I try using System browser (firefox), I get this error:
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($HOME is /home/myuser which is owned by myuser.)
When I try using System browser (Chromium or google chrome), I get this error:

```
49188:49188:0627/133853.753488:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
```

When I try using System browser (Chromium or google chrome), with the –no-sandbox option. The browser fails to start it does like flashing then nothing is shown. And I get this error:

```
No protocol specified
[49640:49672:0627/134038.493709:ERROR:bus.cc(393)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "
```

Given that the type of the browser doesn’t make any difference. All what I need is to display my results correctly. I prefer to use Matlab browser to achieve the best code portability.

Answer (score 0):

what sort of license do you have? If academic on a campus-wide license you could raise this sort of question directly with MathWorks Support as they will be paying for System Services Maintenance (SMS). They will be better equipped to answer this question and usually respond within 24 hours or so.

Comment: This answer would be better suited as a comment.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out I agree with you entirely. I cannot comment until I have a reputation of 50+ so I cannot do this :(